# Google SDK returns 403 `User Rate Limit Exceeded`

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-translate, google-cloud-sdk

I am currently trying to use the google developer SDK.
In there i am trying to utilize the google translate functionality.
The translation works fine when sending in a request using my access token obtained through the google developer console.
But using this SDK it keeps throwing a `403 User Rate Limit Exceeded`

this is the code in question :

```
googleService.defineAction$(function translateMessage(target, message, projectId) {
    const translateClient = Translate({
        projectId: projectId    
    })
    console.log(target, message)
    return translateClient.translate(message, target)
        .then(function handleTranslateResults(results) {
            console.log('result : ', result)
            return result
        }) 
        .catch(function handle(err) {
            console.log('err : ', err)
        })
})
```

I have billing enabled.
I am the only one sending requests in with only about 10 characters each time.
This is why i am confused about this, there is no possible way i could have hit the limit.

Checking my quotas and request logs confirms this.

I have also tried initializing the translate client outside of the function when the code is loaded in but this produces the same results.

I do know this question has been asked before but none of those answers provide the solution to my problem and i cannot find an explanation for it online.

Comment: check answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646112/what-is-the-rate-limit-for-google-translate-api-v2

Comment: I have already read this answer before, i have set the quota to the highest possible. waited for 15 minutes. sent a request to translate `hello world` to dutch. and it still threw the error

Comment: If the api you are using is indeed this one: https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing Then i would assume there really isn't a rate limit, but that you have not activated the paid teir yet.  Sorry just guessing I have only used firebase and maps api before.

Answer (score 1):

So after looking through the SDK's node module, i found a readme that was different from the one google promotes on github and their examples page.
The issue resided in that the object passed to `Translate({})` must also contain a vaild api key. 
Without it, it will make the requests to the same url the "try this feature in browser" feature in the api manager uses. this url can only be used once or twice before being asked to register for a paid account. after that it will only return 403 "User Limit Rate exceeded".

I have made a PR to the google github where the wrong example resides.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/pull/324